# Sony Smart Glasses Mic Input

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I have a sony developer kit smart eyeglass and was wondering if there are any tutorials to understand java etc and also I am wanting to use voice input methods to control the menus etc.  Am I limited to the built in mic in the touch controller or can I use Bluetooth mics etc connected to my android phone or computer when writing sdk etc.

I really look forward to hearing from someone who can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any tutorials directly on controlling the menu using the microphone.

But you can use microphone on SmartEyeglass just like a regular bluetooth headset. You can find a guide about this on Audio I/O guide on Sony Developer World website in SmartEyeglass section.
Then you can use microphone to do voice recognition.

For sending menu control commands, you would need a different SDK for controlling the SmartEyeglass user interface. You can contact Sony Developer World to check if they can provide such an SDK for your use case.

Best Regards,
Ahmet